# Interpret this image...of a quotient space

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I have a horrible perception of 3d images drawn on a piece of paper.

Is Munkres saying points in the interior of the disk get mapped onto the boundary of the basketball? And all points on on the boundary of the closed unit disk get mapped onto the top of the sphere??

Comment: Basically, yes. Try to think of the disc as a pouch of some stretchable material, with a cord inside the rim. Put the basketball inside the pouch and pull the cord until the opening closes.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, so I am regarding the closed disk embedded in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: It looks like it. So what have you tried for the homeomorphism?

Comment: Well the easiest chart is $(x,y, \sqrt{})$

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, so actually from your example the boundary maps to a single point.

Comment: What, for example, is the usual mapping between complex plane and sphere? How might that help?

Comment: I am not too good with the complex analysis, but stereographic projection comes to mind, projecting to the riemman sphere.

Answer (score 1):

This is describing forming a 2 sphere from a disc by collapsing the boundary circle to a point.

Suppose I had a very very stretch bit of balloon in a little disc, with a solid circle round the outside. I start blowing it, and the interior of the disc bulges out. As I keep blowing, the balloon keeps growing, looking more and more like a sphere, with a tiny circular hole cut out. The hole becomes so small relative to the sphere, you can picture it finally collapsing to a point, leaving you with a complete sphere.